# Put all filenames in a directory into an array

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

In bash I need to put all the filenames of a given directory into an array.  Furthermore I need each file to be one element in the array so that if my directory contains 3 files: `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` my array will look like this.

```
echo $arr
{file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create an array variable with `var=(...)`. A glob for all the files in the current directory is `*`. Together:

```
files=(*)
echo "${files[@]}"
```

You can loop over the array:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Or access individual elements:

```
echo "${files[0]}"
echo "${files[1]}"
echo "${files[2]}"
```

Note the judicious use of double quotes. Those make sure files with whitespace and other special characters are handled correctly.

Comment: It's good to set `shopt -s nullglob` before `file=(*)` so that the array doesn't end up getting a `*` element on empty directories.

Answer (score 2):

Most simple solution is to use:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
files=(*)
```

Comment: Both more thorough _and_ more succinct! This answer should get the higher score, IMO.